# Unable to launch application after changing something in the manifest

Tags: android, manifest

i tried to add a share intent to the manifest but i did something wrong, now when i delete what i added it keeps coming back after i launch the application. So i cant launch the application as i could before, if needed i can add more code or logs. im at a loss

**My Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<activity
    android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.ShareActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_share" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Multi-CMS"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainActivity"
        android:label="Drie-O  CMS"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainAdministration"
        android:label="Administration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComponents"
        android:label="Components"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainUsers"
        android:label="Users"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_Content"
        android:label="Content"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_Label"
        android:label="Label"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_Content_edit"
        android:label="EditContent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_news"
        android:label="MainComp_news"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_News_Edit"
        android:label="MainComp_news_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_Label_edit"
        android:label="MainComp_news_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_AgendaItem"
        android:label="MainComp_news_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComp_AgendaItem_edit"
        android:label="MainComp_news_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.new_content_item"
        android:label="MainComp_news_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
</application>
```

Errors i got when launched:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\r.devries\AndroidStudioProjects\CMS2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(18, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_share').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\r.devries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.166 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: @Sanoop i never changed that, so why would it be a problem now?

Comment: Make sure that you are editing your real manifest. Sometimes, when you get an error in the manifest, Android Studio opens up a tab on the *generated* manifest, the one that blends in information from your dependencies and `build.gradle` settings. Editing that does you no good. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am sorry i got the wrong manifest, this is what it looks like the top activity is what i added and tried to delete and doesnt want to be deleted. i edited the question

Comment: You defined an Activity outside of the application tag. I'm not sure, but it may cause errors

Comment: Could you share String.xml resource file?

Comment: The "doesn't want to be deleted" part is what I am talking about. **Make sure that you are editing your actual manifest**, not some other tab that Android Studio happened to open.

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE That is the problem i cant get rid of it, it wont allow me to delete it.

Comment: @Robbert, Then I think CommonsWare is on the right track

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sorry, that is my awnser, didnt know this was a thing! thank you sir!

Comment: @CommonsWare respond this awnser as an actual awnser and il accept it as an awnser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a build error tied to your manifest, and you double-click on the error in the build output, Android Studio (through 2.0.0) will pop open a tab on *a* manifest.

Unfortunately, it is the wrong manifest.

This is [a long-standing bug in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290), where clicking the error opens up a generated manifest, one that blends information from your module's manifest, libraries, `build.gradle`, etc. Editing this is possible, if you do not mind your changes vanishing as soon as you do your next build.

Make sure that you edit your real module manifest file. The tab will show something like `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` when you are editing the generated one.

Comment: Everything corrects, but it happens to every xml resource file too, not only the manifest ;).
Probably this would be corrected in Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

No resource found that matches the given name (at `'label'` with value `'@string/title_activity_share'`).
Please check you have `title_activity_share` item in your strings.xml.